# How to automatically rotate images if they are vertical

Tags: python, if-statement, directory, python-imaging-library, crop

I recently starting coding a few days ago and I'm trying to write a program that crops images and then stacks them. I am currently still on step one. I want to make it where after the image is cropped, if is no already, rotate it to the horizontal position. Thank you for your time.

Edit: So I was able to get it to rotate, but now my rotated file has giant black boxes at the top and bottom, anyone know how to remove that.

```
from PIL import Image

# Convert list in variables
print("Type in the coordinates for the upper left (x1,y1) and bottom right (x2,y2) points")
coordinates = list(map(int, input("Separate values with a space (x1 y1 x2 y2): ").strip().split()))[:4]
x1, y1, x2, y2 = coordinates
print("Generating image...")

# Accessing file from folder
im = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\Ps\\2.tiff")

# Cropping function
selected_region = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
cropped_region = im.crop(selected_region)
# Current line I am trying to add to rotate images
selected_region = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
cropped_region = im.crop(selected_region)

if (y2-y1)>(x2-x1):
    rotated_image = cropped_region.rotate(90)
else:
    rotated_image = cropped_region
cropped_region.show()
cropped_region.save("C:\\Users\\Alex\Desktop\\Ps\\Output\\2_cropped.tiff", quality=95)
rotated_image.save("C:\\Users\\Alex\Desktop\\Ps\\Output\\rotated.tiff", quality=95)
```

Also, hopefully this isn't asking for too much. So in this code, I am cropping one image, is there a way I can repeat this for all (about 500) images in the same folder (all labelled test1.tiff, test2.tiff, test3.tiff...)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: @AMC So, I just fixed a few things. But now the problem is when I rotate the image. The total size of the final image is the same as the original image. This results in black boxes above and below the rotated image. Is there a way I can fix that.